# shouldChangeCharactersInRange returns false but textfield text is being changed

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode8

I'm trying to prevent any input other than numeric characters in a text view using shouldChangeCharactersInRange function. Here's my code :

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if ((textField.text?.characters.count <= 5) || (string.characters.count == 0)) && string.isNumber() {

        if string.characters.count == 0 {
            labels[range.location].text = "_"
        } else {
            labels[range.location].text = string
        }
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }

}

func isNumber() -> Bool{
    let badCharacters = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet
    return self.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(badCharacters) == nil
}
```

It works in most cases but I can't understand why in some rare cases as string == "^" or string == "¨", the function return false but my textfield is being changed.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UE9GD.jpg)

Can you please explain me how to prevent that behavior or why can't I handle it ?

Comment: How are you sure that function returns false ?

Comment: Cause I can see it while debugging.

Comment: I've been testing all keys on my keyboard and it occurs only with "^", "¨" and "`".

Comment: print your "bad characters" set. I think you should create it yourself

Comment: I can (and I will try) but I can assure you that _func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool_ returns false so _func isNumber() -> Bool_ has logically nothing to do with that weird behavior.

Comment: Added a screenshot.

Comment: So the problem here is that you see the "^" in the field ?

Comment: Yes. By returning false, _func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool_ should prevent this. And it does. For anything (that I don't want) except "^", "¨" and "`"....